# Is it possible to upload xlsx file to aws S3 storage on coding in django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my code (I am writing some data to existing xlsx file)

```
wb = load_workbook(EXCEL_FILE) # it is a directory to my excel file (inside of project)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    Sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]
    Sheet1.cell(row = 4, column = 5).value = user_surname
    Sheet1.cell(row = 5, column = 5).value = user_name
    Sheet1.cell(row = 6, column = 5).value = address
    Sheet1.cell(row = 7, column = 5).value = city_and_country
    Sheet1.cell(row = 8, column = 5).value = phone_number
    Sheet1.cell(row = 9, column = 5).value = passport

    length = len(products)
    rows = [x for x in range(1,length+1)]
    sum_list = []
    for (row,product,count,price,attr_name,attr_value) in zip(rows,products,product_count,product_price,attr_names,attr_values):
        length = len(attr_name)
        additional_info = []
        for name,value in zip(attr_name,attr_value):
            name_and_value = name + ': ' + value
            additional_info.append(name_and_value)
        print(additional_info)
        Sheet1.cell(row = 3+row, column = 7).value = product + "--" +"-".join(additional_info)
        Sheet1.cell(row = 3+row, column = 9).value = count
        Sheet1.cell(row = 3+row, column = 10).value = price
        real_price = price[0:-2]
        total_one_product = int(real_price) * count
        sum_list.append(total_one_product)
    currency = Currency.objects.last()
    uzs = currency.UZS if currency else 10300
    total_price_usd = sum(sum_list)/uzs
    Sheet1.cell(row = 10, column = 14)  .value = round(total_price_usd,2)
    

    wb.save("demo.xlsx") # file is being saved to the directory inside of Project and sent to courier as an attachement
```

Now i want to save it to aws S3 storage with user_name and order_id as i can attach this file to the mail i am trying to send from aws storage
if anyone knows how to do it, Please help me out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing your file as demo.xlsx you can upload that file to S3 with below following snippets

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client.Object(bucket_name, file_key).upload_file(
            local_filepath)
```

You should have setup the access levels via IAM role which is the best practices. if not you've to set access keys with limited access to specific bucket alone.

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name,
                     Key=file_key,
                     Body=rel_path| 'file contents')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. But is it possible to upload the file  without saving  it after editing ?

Comment: You mean `bucket_url` by saying `bucked_name` , Amazon web service was set up!

Comment: bucket name in the sense the exact bucket name not url!

you can't upload a file without saving it!

Comment: if you have the content on a variable then you can make use of second snippet which directly writes the variable contents to s3 object